# highlighting menu link using javascript, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am using the below script for main menu highlight ( menu1 )

HTML

- menu1
- menu2

SCRIPT

```
var link = document.location.href.split('/').slice(-1);   // retrieve page name
$('nav#test1 li a.active').removeClass('active');        // remove class 'active'
$('nav#test1 li a[href$="'+link+'"]').addClass('active');
```

ex: www.example.com/content/menu1

menu1 menu2 menu3...

But, if the the URL is of

www.example.com/content/menu1/story.html

how do i highlight menu1 if the title/page appends the menu1 by jquery or javascript.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var link = document.location.href.split('/')[4];
```

Should solve your problem